# Scala - Get Last Inserted ObjectId Using Casbah MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

Is there any way to get last inserted ObjectId? i can't find it on their documentation or maybe i am not digging far enough, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The insert method will mutate the underlying DBObject and add a `_id` field if it doesn't exist.

```
> val document = MongoDBObject("{x: 101}")
> collection.insert(document)
> println(document)

{ "x" : 101 , "_id" : { "$oid" : "58204e47e9dd35767edb0225"}}
```

So you can check your inserted document for the `_id`